# Difference between Callback<P,R> and Function<T,R>

Tags: java, javafx, lambda

[Callback](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/util/Callback.html) and [Function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html) seem very similar. The only substantial difference I can find is that Function has some utility methods for composing functions, while Callback doesn't.

In my own code, I find myself sometimes using one and sometimes the other, without really thinking about it. Sure enough, they both happily accept lambdas of the same form.

As `Callback` is a JavaFX class, I assume it came second, so my question is- why was it created? Is there any **concrete** reason to use one over the other? Can one be safely cast as the other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Callback predates Function. ("Since JavaFX 2.0".) JavaFX needed that functionality, Java didn't have it, so JavaFX defined it. Then Java 8 introduced it in a more general context.

You cannot cast one to the other, as neither is a subtype of the other. You can however assign one to another via lambdas, since the signature is the same.

In other words:

```
Callback<String, Integer> lengthCB = s -> s.length(); // or String::length
Function<String, Integer> lengthFunc = (Function<String, Integer>) lengthCB ;
```

gives a class cast exception, but

```
Callback<String, Integer> lengthCB = s -> s.length(); // or String::length
Function<String, Integer> lengthFunc = lengthCB::call ;
```

is fine.

As for which to use, if you're implementing them with lambdas (or method references), the question is usually moot, as the compiler will just infer the type from the context.

If you're actually assigning them to variables, or implementing the interface with a class definition (not a lambda), then you are forced to choose a type. You should do so based on the desired use and context: if it's going to be passed to a JavaFX object that expects a callback, use a callback, otherwise use a function.

If you're defining them as fields in a class, you should generally prefer `Function`, as it is intended for a wider context. Again if it's directly being used in a JavaFX control, it may make more sense to use a `Callback`.

Answer (score 1):

Both interfaces are "functional" or single abstract method interfaces. One of the reasons why lambdas are implemented the way they are, is because single abstract method interface is an established pattern in Java, and Callback is an example.

It might be considered a smell to use a class that comes from `javafx` where you have `java.util.function.Function` which comes with some additional useful default methods outside the UI code.